# Chrome version 109 breaking change on custom tag

Tags: html, css

I'm using the following HTML and CSS on Chrome since April 2021, it was working

```
<head>

    <style>
        x-sentence {
            border-bottom: solid;
        }


        x-word {
            display: inline-flex;
            flex-direction: column-reverse;
        }

        x-word::after {
            content: '';
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <x-sentence>
        <x-word>Hello world</x-word> nice view <x-word>there</x-word>
    </x-sentence>

</body>
```

It is still working on Safari (both macOS and iOS):

[image]

It is working on older version of Chrome, e.g. [version 107](https://google-chrome.en.uptodown.com/mac/download/86741131)(November 28, 2022)

Reference: https://github.com/chinese-words-separator/chinese-words-separator.github.io/issues/5

However, on latest version of Chrome (109), the above HTML and CSS no longer works:

[image]

Please do note that a problem (border-bottom) can be fixed by using non-custom tags, e.g., changing the `x-sentence` custom tag to `div class='x-sentence'`; the text "nice view" is still erroneously aligned even when `x-word` custom tag is changed to `span class='x-word` though. However, I'm using custom tags so that my [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chinese-words-separator/gacfacdpfimbkgcnlegknnmcccjgcbnp) and [Safari extension](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/chinese-words-separator/id1598790017) can prevent CSS and style collision problems with the page, I still prefer to solve the problem while still using custom tags

Did Chrome 109 introduced a bug? Or was I relying on non-standard HTML behavior for custom tags?

Is it possible to fix the problem while still using custom tags?

**UPDATE 2023-Jan-28**

Problem solved by [fubar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4604701/fubar)

The change needed so that things works like it was pre-Chrome 109:

```
vertical-align: ${guideOnTop ? 'text-bottom' : 'baseline'};
```

[image]

The added code has no side effects on Safari, works on Safari too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm wondering whether the default styles for otherwise unstyled elements changed in Chrome. Adding a little more CSS fixes the issue.

```html
<head>

    <style>
        x-sentence {
            border-bottom: solid;
            display: inline-block;
        }


        x-word {
            display: inline-flex;
            flex-direction: column-reverse;
            vertical-align: bottom;
        }

        x-word::after {
            content: '';
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <x-sentence>
        <x-word>Hello world</x-word> nice view <x-word>there</x-word>
    </x-sentence>

</body>
```

Comment: That destroys the spacing between words, the `Hello world nice view there` becomes `Hello worldnice viewthere`

Comment: I was more demonstrating that a little more CSS could fix the issue. Changing it further gives the above.

Comment: Thanks, your latest code works like a charm. I just need to change the `vertical-align: bottom` to `vertical-align: text-bottom`. `bottom`  works ok too, but somehow it makes the text move a few pixels higher when a `border-bottom` is dynamically added (e.g., via mouse hover), `text-bottom` works perfect, it has no side effects when `border-bottom` is dynamically added